# jHipster inject "entity" on new created entity dialog controller - purpose?

Tags: angular, entity, jhipster

When jHipser create new entity(newEntity), in newentity-dialog.controller.js it injects entity:

```
NewEntityDialogController.$inject = ['$timeout', '$scope', '$stateParams', '$uibModalInstance', '$q', '*entity*'];
```

and then use it to set vm.newEntity:

```
    vm.newEntity = *entity*;
```

I don't understand what is entity, where is defined and what is purpose of that.

Answer (score 0):

This answer assumes your entity is named `NewEntity` like in your question.  `entity` is defined in your entity's state.  If you look in the entity's state file `new-entity.state.js` (located at `src/main/webapp/app/entities/new-entity/new-entity.state.js`), you will see the following in the resolve section:

```
resolve: {
    entity: ['$stateParams', 'NewEntity', function($stateParams, NewEntity) {
        return NewEntity.get({id : $stateParams.id}).$promise;
    }]
}
```

Resolve is part of ui-router, allowing you to inject custom content/data into a state.  The `entity` section of the `resolve` loads your entity by ID and makes it available under the `entity` variable in your controller.

For more information on how `resolve` works, see the [ui-router Github wiki](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki):

> You can use `resolve` to provide your controller with content or data that is custom to the state. resolve is an optional map of dependencies which should be injected into the controller.